# How to auto alter the code snippets in a file while executing the same file in runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I have an sample.py as below

```
a = [1, 2, 3]         
b = 4                                                                                                                                
a.append(b)
print(a)
```

In the above code I am good to extend the array by appending 'b' to 'a'. Now the List 'a' prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This value is going to last only till the time the code executes.
If I rerun the code, the values will reintialise.

So, How to replace the snippet
"
a = [1, 2, 3]
with a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
" by alternatively changing the file itself, so that next time I open the file I see "a = [1,2,3,4] appear in it. Also when we rerun it again, we must get "a" printed as "[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]"

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am simply trying to mimic a "Machine Learnable" python code which will in turn able to re program itself during its own execution. To be more precise, I want to auto build an Array of data physically written in a program using the same program execution. It's more like adding on extra snippets generated through some function using write Operations, but to the same file altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *conveniently* modify the python script while you are running it (although it is only a text file so *in principle* you could write to it).

If what you are trying to do is to save a python list to a file and then read it in again later, it is best to use a **separate data file**.

There are many formats that you could use, but a couple of obvious choices are:

**JSON**

This is a text file format which is human-readable and the contents are similar to how the object would appear in Python source code.  Here is an example of writing the list to a JSON file, and then reading it into another variable and printing it:

```
import json

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

filename = "a.json"

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(a))
    
with open(filename) as f:
    b = json.loads(f.read())

print(b)
```

Here is the JSON file that is produced in this case.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Pickle data**

This is a binary format which will allow more types of objects to be written than can be written to JSON, and will be more efficient and for example you can write floating point numbers without introducing rounding errors, but the file contents are not human-readable.

Here is a similar example to the above, but using `pickle`:

```
import pickle

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

filename = "a.pickle"

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
    
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    b = pickle.load(f)

print(b)
```

As mentioned, this data file is not human-readable. It might look something like this if you tried to inspect it directly:

```
�]q(KKKKe
```

To give an example of why it might sometimes be better to use pickle, if for example you tried to write a tuple rather than a list:

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

you will find with a JSON file that it is written in the same way as a list (because JSON does not have a separate way to represent a tuple), so it will be read back in as a list and you will have to convert it back into a tuple if that is what you want.  But with pickle, the variable will come back as a tuple automatically.

---

### Update

If you *really* want to overwrite the program itself as a means to save data, then I suggest that you use a separate module that *only* contains the variable of relevance, and `import` it from that module. For example:

In `main.py`

```
from setvars import a
b = 4
a.append(b)
print(a)

with open("setvars.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("a = " + repr(a) + "\n")
```

In `setvars.py`

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

After running, `setvars.py` now contains:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But note that this is not a common practice.

It might also be safer to write it initially to a temporary filename and then rename it.  For example:

```
import os

...

with open("setvars.py.tmp", "w") as f:
    f.write("a = " + repr(a) + "\n")

os.rename("setvars.py.tmp", "setvars.py")
```

Comment: Thanks @alaniwi. This is a good alternative for the python List Append operation, using a separate JSON dump file, to build our Array. This also ensures us not losing our original array information once after completing a program execution. But, is it really not possible to write data to the same file during its own execution added as a statement ("a = [1, 2, 3, 4]") written onto itself ? Could you confirm ?

Comment: @user13915049 I have not come across anyone trying to save data by overwriting the program itself. If you must do so, then at least I suggest that you write to a separate module that *only* sets the variables of interest, and import them from that module into your main code.

Comment: @user13915049 See my update which I have now added to the end of my answer.